# What lives above the last accessible address in the stack?

Tags: memory, x86, intel

I've asked people before about why the stack doesn't start at 0x7fff...c before, and was told that typically 0x800... onwards is for the kernel, and the cli args and environment variables live at the top of the user's stack which is why it starts below 0x7fff...c. But I recently tried to examine all the strings with the following program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
  const char *ptr = argv[0];
  while (1) {
    printf("%p: %s\n", ptr, ptr);
    size_t len = strlen(ptr);
    ptr = (void *)ptr + len + 1;
  }
}
```

However, after displaying all my environment variables, I see the following (I compiled the program to an executable called `./t`):

```
0x7ffc19f84fa0: <final env variable string>
0x7ffc19f84fee: _=./t
0x7ffc19f84ff4: ./t
0x7ffc19f84ff8: 
0x7ffc19f84ff9: 
0x7ffc19f84ffa: 
0x7ffc19f84ffb: 
0x7ffc19f84ffc: 
0x7ffc19f84ffd: 
0x7ffc19f84ffe: 
0x7ffc19f84fff:
```

So it appears there's one extra empty byte after the null terminator for the `./t` string at bytes `0x7ffc19f84ff4..0x7ffc19f84ff7`, and after that I segfault so I guess that's the base of the stack. What actually lives in the remaining "empty" space before kernel memory starts?

Edit: I also tried the following:

```
global _start
extern print_hex, fgets, puts, print, exit

section .text
_start:
  pop rdi
  mov rcx, 0
  _start_loop:
    mov rdi, rsp
    call print_hex
    pop rdi
    call puts
    
    jmp _start_loop

  mov rdi, 0
  call exit
```

where `print_hex` is a routine I wrote elsewhere. It seems this is all I can get

```
0x00007ffcd272de28
./bin/main
0x00007ffcd272de30
abc
0x00007ffcd272de38
def
0x00007ffcd272de40
ghi
0x00007ffcd272de48
make: *** [Makefile:47: run] Segmentation fault
```

so it seems that even in `_start` we don't begin at 0x7fff...

Comment: Depends on the OS.  On Linux at least, the space above the initial user-space RSP is initialized by the kernel.  (With argv[], envp[], and space above that for the pointed-to strings.  And whatever else apparently.)  Stack ASLR also randomizes the stack pointer relative to a page boundary.  I don't know where it leaves a gap, above the pointed-to env strings or between then and argv/envp.

Comment: It would probably make sense to examine memory with GDB, or use `fwrite` or a `write` system call and pipe into `hexdump -C`.  Although I guess we can conclude that those bytes must be zeros, from the fact that `strlen` returned `1` so the output addresses are consecutive.

Comment: [Here's the linux code that builds the user mode stack](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/83633ed70c50d3a8470c7e40732efa165dcc2dc7/fs/exec.c). Enjoy looking for that "extra" byte.

Comment: Soon or later you'll end up in an unmapped memory. On Linux `argv[x]` points into an "information block" in the stack. Immediately above and below it the ABI says that's a variable amount of *unspecified* data. Once you get past that you'll end in an unmapped base. In general, ASLR will move the stack down from the top of the lowest half of the address space. You can use the proc pseudo-FS to see where the stack starts.